# What does $L^{1,\infty}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, notation

What is the definition of $L^{1,\infty}$ in the sense of Lebesgue functions?

Comment: What's the context? As in, what's the sentence or statement you've met this notation, and where? This seems like an uncommon enough notation that the author might have specified it somewhere.

Comment: See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space